# AttributeError HELP!

Tags: python

```
  class Account:
  def __init__(self, initial):
      self.balance = initial
      def deposit(self, amt):
          self.balance = self.balance + amt
      def withdraw(self,amt):
          self.balance = self.balance - amt
      def getbalance(self):
          return self.balance

a = Account(1000.00)
a.deposit(550.23)
a.deposit(100)
a.withdraw(50)

print a.getbalance()
```

I get this error when I run this code.. AttributeError: Account instance has no attribute 'deposit'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what the above answers mean is that instead your code should be like this - remember unlike other languages, indentation is serious business in Python:

```
class Account(object):

    def __init__(self, initial):
        self.balance = initial

    def deposit(self, amt):
        self.balance += amt

    def withdraw(self, amt):
        self.balance -= amt

    def getbalance(self):
        return self.balance

a = Account(1000.00)
a.deposit(550.23)
a.deposit(100)
a.withdraw(50)

print a.getbalance()
```

and now you'll get 1600.23 instead of an error.

Answer (score 5):

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, initial):
        self.balance = initial
    def deposit(self, amt):
        self.balance = self.balance + amt
    def withdraw(self,amt):
        self.balance = self.balance - amt
    def getbalance(self):
        return self.balance
```

The way you defined them, they were local to the `__init__` method, and thus useless.

Answer (score 2):

You've indented them too deep. They're inner functions of the `__init__()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have remarked:

You have not correctly shown the code that you actually ran. What appears here has the `def __init__ ...` at the same level as the `class` statement; this would have caused a (compile time) SyntaxError, not a (run time) AttributeError.